# Add and delete item from an array

Tags: angular, typescript

I try to write a method to delete and add item to array i need delete and add methods in a easy way because i am not familiar typescript

```
export class NgForComponent implements OnInit {

  Sayilar: number[];
  constructor() {
    this.Sayilar = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

html

```
        <div>
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let sayi of Sayilar">
          {{sayi}}
        </li>
    </ul>


    </div>

    <button >Delete</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 <li *ngFor="let sayi of Sayilar;let i = index">
          {{sayi}}
  <button (click)="deleteSayilar(i)">Delete</button>
 </li>


in typescript
deleteSayilar(i){
   this.Sayilar.splice(i,1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to place the delete within the ngFor inorder to get the clicked item, otherwise you would not know which item to delete , or change your interface in order to identify which item to be deleted.

```
<ul>
 <li *ngFor="let sayi of Sayilar">
          {{sayi}}
  <button (click)="delete(sayi)">Delete</button>
 </li>
</ul>
```

and then in TS,

```
delete(item : any){
   this.Sayilar.splice(item ,1);
}
```

Comment: Property 'remove' does not exist on type 'number[]' it says like this in TS

Comment: sure to set the compiler target to es6 in your tsconfig.

Comment: how i should add method after handle this problem

Comment: this.Sayilar = this.Sayilar.filter(e => e !== item)

Comment: how can it know the number will be add ?

Comment: what do you mean by that

Comment: for example i want to add 7 to array how should write 7 like a text box?

Comment: just add another text box and use array.push

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
 <li *ngFor="let sayi of Sayilar">
          {{sayi}}
  <button (click)="delete(sayi)">Delete</button>
 </li>
</ul>
```

and your ts

```
delete(sayi){
this.Sayilar.filter(m => m !== sayi)
}
```